# Install Refferar Tracking Not Working From Google Play Store

Tags: android

App is live on Play Store but Broadcast Receiver not getting fired when app is downloaded from play store.

Broadcast Action is   `action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"`

But this broadcast works fine when fired from terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Your app must be launched manually before it can receive this broadcast. Until then, your `BroadcastReceiver` is inactive.